# Are there any scientific projects currently pursuing Uplift?

Tags: uplift

The moral implications aside, I remember wondering in the past if there were any projects that were actually pursuing something like David Brin's Uplift.

> This future history depicts a huge galactic civilization responsible for "uplifting" all forms of life which are potentially capable of building and operating interstellar spaceships for themselves.

I know there are projects that are examining various species to determine their level of intelligence, but are there any that are doing concentrated breeding and teaching programs to attempt to raise the level of intelligence?

Comment: There is certainly a lot of animal cognition research and brain--machine interface work (though I believe still at a very fundamental level) going on. Presumably these would be the foundation of such an effort.

Comment: well, people love dogs that try to talk, so if you give that another 10 or 20 thousand years, maybe we'll have dogs that can actually say a few words. not exactly a breeding program, though.

Comment: That would be really ethically shady. Start splicing human DNA into chimps and what you end up with ... is it human or a chimp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other than the most obvious, long-term examples like dogs, I'm not aware of any "Uplift" programs like you mention *per se*. As you've probably seen, most current studies seems to deal in the measurement of animal intelligence, with the most recent showing of high level tool using ability of cephalopods and tool-using AND tool-making ability of corvids (specifically rooks). Some of these studies involved teaching the rooks to do various things, so once we have a qualitative measurement of intelligence, it will be a short jump to selective breeding these "smarter" animals.
You know, come to think of it, I seem to recall something I read once about selective rat-breeding for some kind of intelligence performance... if I remember/find it I'll post the link.

UPDATE: Some links. These cases are actual genetic manipulation, not selective breeding

[Smart Rats NatGeo](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2009/11/091112-smartest-rat-memory.html)

[Research Article](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0007486)